# When I save an imagefilename it shows [Object: null prototype] { title: 'value', description: 'value' }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I've been stuck for this error for several hours, i'm trying to save my title, description, and image into my mongoDb atlas. It only saves title and description but not the image.

When I try to display it on console log it shows this error:
[Object: null prototype] { title: 'value', description: 'value' }
CONTENT SAVED!

Can anyone help me why it says Object: null prototype? Thank you in advance.

Here's my `index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const User = require('../models/user-model')
const Post = require('../models/post-model')

router.use(bodyParser.json())

const uploadPath = path.join('public', Post.coverImageBasePath)

const imageMimeTypes = ['images/jpg', 'images/png', 'images/gif']
const upload = multer({
    dest: uploadPath,
    fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, imageMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype))
    }
})

//SERVE EJS FILES:

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('foodie/home')
})

router.get('/content', (req, res) => {
    res.render('foodie/posts/all')
})

router.get('/content/create', (req, res) => {
    res.render('foodie/posts/new')
})

//SAVE CONTENT
router.post('/', upload.single('coverImage') , async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const fileName = req.file != null ? req.file.filename : null
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        coverImage: fileName
    })

    try {
        const newPost = await post.save()
        console.log('CONTENT SAVED!')
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

This is my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const coverImageBasePath = 'uploads/contentCover'

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    coverImage: {
        type: String
    },
    publishDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
module.exports.coverImageBasePath = coverImageBasePath
```

This error shows up:

[Object: null prototype] { title: 'value', description: 'value' }

I was expecting to get a filename and not an Object null.

Comment: user22864195, at first, you'd better to check the middleware ```upload.single('coverImage')``` , then when  there is no ```req.file.filename```, your const variable "fileName" 's value is null, if so, maybe null can be saved in your database. I think that is not ok for you to get a filename from the correct data with the meaningful value of coverImage.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please make sure that you are sending the response for save content POST request is of type multipart/form-data?

Eg:

```html
<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
        <label for="description">Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="desc">
        <label for="file">Choose a file to upload:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
```